# Why are NVL functions called "NVL"?

Tags: java, database, nvl

Sometimes I see an `nvl()` function in code. In the case of Java, it looks like this:

```
public static String nvl(String value, String alternateValue) {
    if (value == null)
        return alternateValue;

    return value;
}
```

I understand what this function does, but I don't understand why it's called `nvl`. Why not `checkNotNull` or `returnNotNull`? What does NVL stand for?

I guess **N**ull **V**alue **L**...?

Comment: It's **N**ull **V**a**L**ue or **N**ull **V**alue **L**ogic according to [this](http://www.abbreviations.com/term/157605)

Comment: I vote **N**ull **V**a**L**ue

Comment: As far as I know NVL stand for Null VaLue.  I think it keep the standards of SQL which was a well versed function for database developers.  Moreover we are not returning any boolean value to name the method name as isNull() or checkNull() something like that.

Comment: its simply Null Value

Comment: This function is sub-optimal for languages like java, in which you have have the following construction: `string val = value != null ? value : alternative`. Besides, in a function call, both values are evaluated firstly than the function call, this can lead to programming mistakes, I actually see this happen very often. Prefer ternary operator

Comment: also because nvl exists in some languages, like oracle PLSQL

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As others have pointed out in comments, it probably stands for "null value" or "null value logic". It might just as well be called "dflt" (or similar abbreviation) for "default".

And, in Java, it should really be using generics so that it can work on any type ;)